# Is it possible to write to a file from a custom reporter?

Tags: intern

I'm trying to write a custom reporter that will output the intern test results to a file, but I've reached a roadblock.

I managed to get hold of the Node file system API via Intern's dojo loader, but neither writeFile or writeFileSync do anything (the difference being that writeFileSync locks up the process).

A minimal version of my reporter code:

```
define(["node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/node!fs"], function (fs) {
    var buffer = "";
    return {
        "/test/pass": function(test) {
            buffer += test.id + " passed\n";
        },
        "/test/fail": function(test) {
            buffer += test.id + " failed\n";
        },
        "/runner/end": function () {
            fs.writeFileSync("result.txt", buffer, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
                console.log("File saved");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

If I replace the write call with a console log, I get the expected data, so everything else appears to be working fine.

Edit: Modified code that works:

```
define(["node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/node!fs"], function (fs) {
    var buffer = "";
    return {
        "/test/pass": function(test) {
            buffer += test.id + " passed\n";
        },
        "/test/fail": function(test) {
            buffer += test.id + " failed\n";
        },
        "/runner/end": function () {
            fs.writeFileSync("result.txt", buffer);
            console.log("File saved");
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: are you running your tests using node or a browser?

Comment: I'm using node. The tests are functional tests running against a local Selenium server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to write files from reporters—the [`lcov` reporter](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/lib/reporters/lcov.js) does exactly this. However, until Intern 1.2 is released, asynchronous I/O operations have the potential to not complete properly because the process is forcibly terminated at the end of the test run.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the issue with the process being forcibly terminated - but does that explain why the call to writeFileSync just hangs? It looks like the lcov reporter is essentially doing the same thing, but via Istanbul, so perhaps my issue is more how I'm importing the file system.

Comment: Synchronous functions do not have callbacks.

Comment: Doh... looks like that was the problem, I removed the callback and it now works. I of course didn't check for a different signature when changing from the async version :facepalm:.